# Migrating from OS X Server 10.6.6 to 10.7 (Lion) - any worries?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, mac-osx-server, osx-lion

I use the built-in server features of OS X Snow Leopard Server to run a local copy of Apache, MySQL, PHP, and Perl. I develop against these so it is very important to me that they stay available after the upgrade and retain their configurations. I have to upgrade so I can develop in the latest version of XCode, but is there anything I ought to know or do to prepare before I perform the upgrade? I am obviously going to make an image of my current environment, but is there anything else I can do to make this go smoothly?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done the upgrade yet on any of our server machines running 10.6, but MySQL isn't included with Lion Server and the database controls are no longer there.

Apple has a [knowledge base entry](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4828?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on this.